# Install scss and less on dreamweaver cs6 mac

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am trying to install scss and less on dreamweaver cs6 on macbook pro. I followed all the steps and added the extensions in both the extension.txt file and MMDocumentTypes.xml but my dreamweaver is still not recognising the scss or less.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What steps? What instructions? What extension are you using? Please provide more detail.

Comment: http://www.dreamdealer.nl/articles/how_to_get_scss_and_less_files_to_open_in_dreamweaver.html

Comment: and many more link these

Comment: The instructions you linked to are for Windows, but you said you're using a Mac.

Comment: the instructions are identical for both, I have checked other articles as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using dreamweaver cs6 for for less/scss installation, I have turned towards sublime text.

This is a better choice, because of packages available which can be installed to support less/scss